# Open Graph Object Categories.

Tags: facebook, object, facebook-opengraph, categories

Documentation on using multiple objects describes creation of certain objects as "categories" while using custom properties to assign them.

It also says that:

> Note: Facebook only reads object relationships three deep, so there’s no need to map out more than 3 relationships for each object.

If an object has more than 3 custom properties which are references to other objects, how are these relationships determined?

Is it the first 3 in the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It only reads 3 **deep** not **wide**. You can (and should) have as many properties on an object that it needs.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Follow up Q.. is there a way to force a category aggregation while testing? So far having multiple users act on different objects within same category seems to create multiple single stories.